# JS - checking whether the numbers are in the text

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check whether a digit is in a string, e.g.:

```
var w1 = "1" && "5" && "9";
var newX = "1,7,9,5"
if (newX.indexOf(w1) > -1) {
            alert("is it");
            break;
}
```

Unfortunately, if only 9 is in the array, the code shows an alert. How can I check if 1, 5 or 9 is in string (newX)?

Answer (score 2):

```
var w1 = "1" && "5" && "9";
```

doesn't do what you think it does.

You will need to make that an array and check each item separately:

```js
var w1 = ["1", "5", "9"];

var newX = "1,7,9,5"

if (w1.some(function(item) {
  return newX.indexOf(item) > -1
})) {
  alert("is it");
}
```

Comment: Wow, both of us even used `some`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `some` and `every` are great. Lived without knowing about them for way too long! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var w1 = "1" && "5" && "9";
```

has exactly the same result as this:

```
var w1 = "9";
```

because the `&&` operator evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that's truthy,¹ evalutes its right-hand operand and makes that the result of the expression.

> How Ihave check 1,5 or 9 is in string (newX)?

You'll need a loop of some kind. For instance, you can put the things you want to check in an array and then use `some`:

```js
var w1 = ["1", "5", "9"];
var newX = "1,7,5"; // Removed the 9 just for clarity
// This one finds it
if (w1.some(function(entry) {
  return newX.indexOf(entry) != -1;
})) {
    console.log("is it");
}
newX = "4, 7, 8";
// This one doesn't
if (w1.some(function(entry) {
  return newX.indexOf(entry) != -1;
})) {
    console.log("is it 2");
}
```

In `Array#some`, the callback is called repeatedly. If the callback ever returns a truthy value, the result of `some` is `true`; if not, it's `false`.

With ES2015, that `some` callback can be more concise:

```
if (w1.some(entry => newX.indexOf(entry) != -1)) {
    console.log("is it");
}
```

---

¹ "truthy" - A value that coerces true when treated as a boolean. Values are either *falsy* or *truthy*. The falsy values are `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `undefined`, `null`, and of course, `false`. The truthy values are all others.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions and [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

```js
var newX = "1,7,9,5"
if (newX.match(/(?=.*1)(?=.*5)(?=.*9)/)) {
   console.log("is it");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As some people already stated, you want to make your w1 and newX variables arrays. In my opinion, its also easier to compare numbers to numbers instead of trying to compare strings of numbers. Some of the above solutions might work for you but it can also be achieved with nested loops. Heres a snippit of what it looks like doing it my way.

```
var w1 = [1,5,9];
var newX = [1,7,9,5]

for (i = 0; i < newX.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < w1.length; j++) {
        if (w1[j] == newX[i])
        alert("Found " + w1[j] + "!");
    }
}
```

We first loop through the array newX and check each index (i) then we loop through the w1 array and check to see if the current index (j) is equal to the newX current index. If so, we output it to the alert. Let me know if this method works for you. If you need help understanding any of this feel free to ask me!